# Requeuing Kinesis messages when processing failures occur

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

Does Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder support the requeuing of messages as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#polled-errors)?

In my `@StreamListener` I am throwing a new `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.RequeueCurrentMessageException`, but I see in my logs that `org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.kinesis.KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is logging `Consider to use 'errorChannel' flow for the compensation logic`, and immediately after this in the logs I see the shard is checkpointed. This is not the behavior I expected after reading the documentation about how to requeue messages using Spring Cloud Stream. I expected that the Kinesis message would be redelivered and my `@StreamListener` would process the same message again.

Currently we're using Spring Cloud Stream Kinesis Binder `2.0.1.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to learn more about Kinesis and how it works. There is just no a single record acknowledging. The checkpointing is about an offset commit after reading some number of records from the shard.

Technically we even may not want to checkpoint at all and we still get next iterator for processing. We need checkpoint in the case of crash of our application. So, next time when we restart, we will continue from the point where we left. The logic behind Kinesis stream processing is fully similar to what we have with Apache Kafka: some log of records and cursor walking through them. To remember the point we have been, it is better to store that point from time to time. Although it is not mandatory.

The point is that we don't process records from the shard individually: we really get some set of them requesting shard iterator from the stream. And if we fail with some message from that set, it doesn't mean that the whole iterator cannot be committed.

It is possible with Kinesis to restart consuming from the specific offset (coming back in the log) as a matter of error handling, but we may end up processing the rest of records one more time.

Therefore it is better to handle errors with records in the target application and let Kinesis to commit offset as it is processed. An error handler may re-send failed message back to the same stream or store it into some other Dead-Letter Stream...

The mentioned exception has this JavaDoc:

```
/**
 * When using a {@code PollableMessageSource} throw this exception to cause the current
 * message to be requeued in the broker so that it will be redelivered on the next poll.
 *
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.1
 *
 */
public class RequeueCurrentMessageException extends RuntimeException {
```

The `KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` is not *pollable*, therefore throwing such an  exception won't make any difference. And even if we could handle it somehow, it is still not going to be redelivery since there is no such a thing in Kinesis according its architecture.

Comment: If I use manual checkpointing and don't checkpoint when I encounter an error processing message A, how can I ensure that my ```@StreamListener``` will reprocess message A without restarting my microservice? Will the next shard iteration re-deliver that same message to my service? I understand that it may also deliver messages that I was able to successfully process and that we'd have to have logic in place to detect those as well.

Comment: No, it is not. The cursor is still active and its in-memory position. It is going to deliver to you next set of records. The checkpoint is only relevant between restarts. To redeliver the failed message, you need to send it back to that stream from your error handler.